# Integral w.r.t. a cumulative density function

Tags: probability, integration, cumulative-distribution-functions

I was reading a paper and couldn't understand the following transition. Could someone tell me where the term of $p^k (\frac{1}{2} − c′)$ comes from in the following transition?

### Def: Cumulative function of interest

$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{for } x < -c' \\
    p^k & \text{for } x \in [-c', 0) \\
    (p + (1 - p) x)^k & \text{for } x \in [0, 1] \\
    1, & \text{for } x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

### Integral of interest

$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x d F(x) = p^k (\frac{1}{2} - c') + \int^{1}_{0} x d F(x) = \cdots
$$

### My attempts

First, I expanded the integral based on the sections as follows;
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x d F(x) = \int^{-c'}_{- \infty} x dF(x) + \int^{0}_{-c'} x dF(x) + \int^{1}_{0} x dF(x) + \int^{\infty}_{1} x dF(x)
$$
Then, i was not sure how to compute each term... could someone tell me how to compute the integral over a CDF?

### Reference

- Appendix B of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07679.pdf)
- Cross reference: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600089/integral-over-a-cumulative-density-function